# Who is Rav Chafetz Ben Yatzliach?

Tags: history

In the Introduction to the Duties of the Heart, Bahya ibn Paquda mentions a book by Rav Chafetz ben Yatzliach which summarises the commandments of the Torah. Is anything known about this figure?

Comment: [חפץ בן יצליח](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A5_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97)

Comment: I was always curious about this. He also mentions 2 seforim that I am unfamiliar with, and aren't on at least my version 17 of otzar hachochma, ספר שרשי הדת, and ספר המקמץ. Do you know about them, as you aren't asking about them?

Comment: @avrah This is Mukkamas https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ibn_Merwan_al-Mukkamas